# ggplot: get discrete legend with scale_fill_gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, legend

I'm trying to recreate an example figure from 'R Graphics Cookbook' p.87.

[image]

I'm trying to recreate with the following code, but I don't get the result:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)

sp <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price))
sp + stat_binhex() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightblue", high="red",
                      breaks=c(0, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000),
                      limits=c(0, 6000))
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that you don't get result?

Comment: add `guide="legend"` (and you may also want to transform `trans="log"`)

Comment: @PoGibas, I get there almost but the legends are not matching. Here's mine: https://imgur.com/8l2543P

Comment: @balkon16 ; could you add the solution as an answer, rather than in your question. thanks

Comment: Don't edit your question title to include "solved". Instead, post an answer, and "accept" it by clicking the checkmark next to it. (You do have to wait 24 hours before accepting your own answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem's solved. Turns out I had to add guide argument:

```
sp <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price))
    sp + stat_binhex() +
      scale_fill_gradient(low="lightblue", high="red",
                          breaks=c(0, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 6000),
                          limits=c(0, 6000), guide = "legend")
```